# archive by year and category: permalink support doesn't work on pagination

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy, archives

I found here:
[Category archive by year with permalink support /category/YYYY](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31422/category-archive-by-year-with-permalink-support-category-yyyy)
the solution to obtain a category-by-year archive also supporting perma:

```
function catyeararchives_init()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'year', EP_CATEGORIES );
    
}
add_action( 'init', 'catyeararchives_init' );
```

The only problem is that pagination doesn't work and after the first page I get a 404 error.
Any idea on how to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you flush your site's permalinks (go to the Settings -> Permalinks page in your admin pages and click **Save Changes**)?

Comment: Yes, I did... It was the first doubt I had...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Category archive by year with permalink support /category/YYYY](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31422/category-archive-by-year-with-permalink-support-category-yyyy)

Comment: Flagged as duplicate. Mentioned Post includes pagination solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: The other solutions don't seem to filter by category: they only obtain a standard archive navigation...